# Which plant is this

Tags: seeds

Can anyone tell me which plant is this? We were given a small plastic cup with mud and seeds and asked to spray water on them. I transplanted the cup to a pot and this came out. But I don't know if this is some plant or just grass. Any idea?[image]

Comment: it would help to know where in the world you are. :)  Also are you able to ask the folks who gave you the pot, perhaps they can shed some ligiht.

Comment: Can't ask them. They left. I got it in the library where I go to study. It was some sort of advertisement of some school.

Answer (score 1):

This is a grass of some kind.  Who ever it was that gave you this project set you up for failure.  Why would they do that?  Is this a rice plant?  Couldn't tell without closer inspection of the awls at the junctions and then also seeing the seeds or flower heads.

[Rice plant information from Science News Magazine.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjq3s-q_7XYAhUD6GMKHSesAJgQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencenews.org%2Farticle%2Fenzymes-aid-rice-plants-arsenic-defenses&psig=AOvVaw1_GJPu2JwkbJ9yMcfEF_Xg&ust=1514869645714480)

This mud in a cup with more moisture sprayed on top would be just fine for rice...what else could it be?

Comment: Why is it set for failure? Will the plant not grow now?
I'm in India. Warm climate. Now it's winter but average temperature is 25 degrees in winter.

Comment: Hi stormy! Your original link took me to a page that said it was re-directing me to a different page. Rather than confuse people, I went to that next page and substituted the link here. Please check my link to make sure it's correct. I really don't know about these plants and don't want to have changed it to something unhelpful to ajay tulsiani. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, went to the right place, thank you Sue!  Look, I check the links I send every single time.  Thank you for checking again...!

Comment: That is the only plant I could imagine making a wet bog work that is a grass that would be part of a class...sure there are others but for a class?  Gotta be rice.  I did not know any other clues other than your Indian name.  These plants are growing nicely.  Is this rice?